# Error while configuring Google App Engine on Pydev in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

i am trying to configure Google App Engine on Eclipse and use it to run a python application locally (on the local host):

for this i used following tutorial as a guide:

http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-python-hello-world-example-using-eclipse/

i followed the steps properly but when i try to use the configuration i get errors the console output is:

## Console Output:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\search.py:232: UserWarning: DocumentOperationResult._code is deprecated. Use OperationResult._code instead.
  'Use OperationResult.%s instead.' % (name, name))

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\search.py:232: UserWarning: DocumentOperationResult._CODES is deprecated. Use OperationResult._CODES instead.
  'Use OperationResult.%s instead.' % (name, name))

WARNING  2012-06-20 14:53:01,451 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 126, in 
    run_file(**file**, globals())

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 122, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 694, in 
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 582, in main
    root_path, {}, default_partition=default_partition)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3142, in LoadAppConfig

raise AppConfigNotFoundError
google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.AppConfigNotFoundError

---

The configuration i am using is:

Windows 7 64 bit

python 2.7

Eclipse Helios

What could be the possible mistake in configuring the GAE?

Additional info : when i try to use the project with GAE manually(ie by using the launcher) it works

---

## Update:

i experimented and discovered that since the workstation and the python installation folder is not in the same directory i get these errors

got the hint from here: 
File
"C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py"

line 582, in main
root_path, {}, default_partition=default_partition)

but when i made another workspace in the same partition i got this as console output and the the local host is still not working

---

## output

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\search.py:232: UserWarning: DocumentOperationResult._code is deprecated. Use OperationResult._code instead.

'Use OperationResult.%s instead.' % (name, name))

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\search.py:232: UserWarning: DocumentOperationResult._CODES is deprecated. Use OperationResult._CODES instead.

'Use OperationResult.%s instead.' % (name, name))

WARNING  2012-06-20 17:20:56,719 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
Runs a development application server for an application.

dev_appserver.py [options]

Application root must be the path to the application to run in this server.
Must contain a valid app.yaml or app.yml file.

Options:

--address=ADDRESS, -a ADDRESS Address to which this server should bind(Defaultlocalhost).

--clear_datastore, -c      Clear the Datastore on startup. (Default false)

--debug, -d                Use debug logging. (Default false)

--help, -h                 View this helpful message.

--port=PORT, -p PORT       Port for the server to run on. (Default 8080)

--allow_skipped_files      Allow access to files matched by app.yaml's
                             skipped_files (default False)

--auth_domain              Authorization domain that this app runs in.
                             (Default gmail.com)

--backends                 Run the dev_appserver with backends support
                             (multiprocess mode).

--blobstore_path=DIR       Path to directory to use for storing Blobstore
                             file stub data.

--clear_prospective_search Clear the Prospective Search subscription index
                             (Default false).

--datastore_path=DS_FILE   Path to file to use for storing Datastore file
                             stub data.
                           (Defaultc:\users\anukoo~1\appdata\local\temp\dev_appserver.datastore)

--debug_imports            Enables debug logging for module imports, showing
                             search paths used for finding modules and any
                             errors encountered during the import process.

--default_partition        Default partition to use in the APPLICATION_ID.
                             (Default dev)

--disable_static_caching   Never allow the browser to cache static files.
                             (Default enable if expiration set in app.yaml)

--disable_task_running     When supplied, tasks will not be automatically
                             run after submission and must be run manually
                             in the local admin console.

--enable_sendmail          Enable sendmail when SMTP not configured.
                             (Default false)

--high_replication         Use the high replication datastore consistency
                             model. (Default false).

--history_path=PATH        Path to use for storing Datastore history.
                             (Default c:\users\anukoo~1\appdata\local\temp\dev_appserver.datastore.history)

--multiprocess_min_port    When running in multiprocess mode, specifies the
                             lowest port value to use when choosing ports. If
                             set to 0, select random ports.
                             (Default 9000)

--mysql_host=HOSTNAME      MySQL database host.
                             Used by the Cloud SQL (rdbms) stub.
                             (Default 'localhost')

--mysql_port=PORT          MySQL port to connect to.
                             Used by the Cloud SQL (rdbms) stub.
                             (Default 3306)

--mysql_user=USER          MySQL user to connect as.
                             Used by the Cloud SQL (rdbms) stub.
                             (Default )

--mysql_password=PASSWORD  MySQL password to use.
                             Used by the Cloud SQL (rdbms) stub.
                             (Default '')

--mysql_socket=PATH        MySQL Unix socket file path.
                             Used by the Cloud SQL (rdbms) stub.
                             (Default '')

--persist_logs             Enables storage of all request and application
                             logs to enable later access. (Default false).

--require_indexes          Disallows queries that require composite indexes
                             not defined in index.yaml.

--show_mail_body           Log the body of emails in mail stub.
                             (Default false)

--skip_sdk_update_check    Skip checking for SDK updates. If false, fall back
                             to opt_in setting specified in .appcfg_nag
                             (Default false)

--smtp_host=HOSTNAME       SMTP host to send test mail to.  Leaving this
                             unset will disable SMTP mail sending.
                             (Default '')

--smtp_port=PORT           SMTP port to send test mail to.
                             (Default 25)

--smtp_user=USER           SMTP user to connect as.  Stub will only attempt
                             to login if this field is non-empty.
                             (Default '').

--smtp_password=PASSWORD   Password for SMTP server.
                             (Default '')

--task_retry_seconds       How long to wait in seconds before retrying a
                             task after it fails during execution.
                             (Default '30')

--use_sqlite               Use the new, SQLite based datastore stub.
                             (Default false)

Invalid arguments

---

seems like the arguments to dev_appserver.py are incorrect any ideas

Comment: Are you trying to run the helloworld?  Why is it calling the search API?

Comment: yes i am just trying to run the helloworld template. but i have no idea why it is using the search api i think because main module is set as dev_appserver.py

Comment: double check your PYTHONPATH and the arguments, make sure you have your project name as the arguments for running your app.  Your app is fine since it runs from your cmd line, it's just the eclipse cfg that's not set up right.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you did the same mistake as mine,then its a very high chance that you have space in the name of your directory

Answer (score 0):

The warnings about deprecated things in search can be ignored. As can the message about the rdbms API if you don't plan on using that.

AppConfigNotFoundError happens when there is no app.yaml in the directory passed to dev_appserver.py. If you followed those instructions, then your app.yaml would be in the 'src' directory, and the 'program arguments' in the build command would be ${project_loc}/src - is this the case? When you run from the command-line, and see it work, what command are you running, and from what location?

Comment: well when i am using the google app launcher application to run the project it works fine but it doesn't work with eclipse id the app.yaml is not present the project should not run with GAE launcher too